# HTML5 Audio (autoplay) на iOS & Android

Tags: html5, аудио

Есть мобильное приложение, доступное через браузер.

При каком-нибудь событии хочу в фоне воспроизводить звук (оповещение).

На компе в браузере всё хорошо, а на устройствах звука нет.

Вот [это](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/wa-ioshtml5/) — не помогло.

Есть решения?

**Пример**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var player  = $('<audio>').appendTo('body').get(0),
            list    = [
                '/sound/1.bell_information.mp3',
                '/sound/2.bell_caution.mp3',
                '/sound/3.bell_warning.mp3'
            ];

        function play(id){
            player.src = list[id];
            player.play();
        }

        play(1);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Добавьте пример кода, который не работает на устройстве

Comment: Добавил пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это строгое ограничение мобильных браузеров. Обойти нельзя никак. Возможно со временем, производители устройств снимут это ограничение, когда стоимость трафика на мобилках приблизится к нулю.

Причем обратите внимание, запрещен не просто автоплей, а прелоад.
Например вот что пишет об этом [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Прочтите секцию http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/wa-ioshtml5/#N101D4 более внимательно, autoplay запрещенн на мобильных устройствах. Связано это с мобильным трафиком.

Comment: В этом и вопрос, можно ли как то обойти данное ограничение?

Comment: В статье так же указано, что - нет. Так же у меня 1.5 года назад тоже стояла такая задача, и я не нашел обходного пути.